# Why do I sometimes have to enclose `.` in `data.frame()` for a named argument in `do`?

Tags: r, dplyr

Why does this not work?

`data.frame(x = rnorm(100)) %>% do(df = .)`

Error message:

```
Error in do_(.data, .dots = lazyeval::lazy_dots(...)) :
  argument ".data" is missing, with no default
```

Instead, I have to enclose the `.` in `data.frame()`:

```
data.frame(x = rnorm(100)) %>% do(df = data.frame(.))
```

Alternatively, this also works:

```
data.frame(x = rnorm(100)) %>% do(., df = .)
```

The example, of course, doesn't make sense. But it can be helpful to save the `data.frame` as a list variable when working with `group_by`.

Here is a more complex problem that seems to be related:

```
library("MatchIt")
n <- 5000
DF <- data.frame(
    x1 = rnorm(n),
    x2 = rbinom(n, 1, 0.5),
    group = rbinom(n, 1, 0.5),
    D = rbinom(n, 1, 0.5))
```

Now this produces an error:

```
DF %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    do(m = matchit(D ~ x1, data = ., exact = "x2"))
```

But it works when I enclose the `.` in `data.frame()`:

```
DF %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    do(m = matchit(D ~ x1, data = data.frame(.), exact = "x2"))
```

I am not sure whether the second example with `matchit` is related but in both cases I have to enclose the `.` in `data.frame()`.

**sessionInfo()**

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] MatchIt_2.4-21 MASS_7.3-33    dplyr_0.4.1    Defaults_1.1-1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] assertthat_0.1  DBI_0.3.1       lazyeval_0.1.10 magrittr_1.5    parallel_3.1.1  Rcpp_0.11.4     tools_3.1.1
```

Comment: Does `mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% do(mod = lm(mpg ~ vs, data = .))` work ?

Comment: Yes, that works. In the 2nd example, the problem also occurs in vary particular circumstances (when I use the `exact` argument). Part of my questions when and why I have to enclose `.` in `data.frame()` or whether it's a problem with my setup. Thanks!

Comment: The second problem isn't actually related to the first, as it's not related to `do`: It's because `matchit` doesn't work on `tbl_df`s. Try `matchit(D ~ x1, data = tbl_df(DF), exact = "x2")`, for example- it gets the same error.

Comment: To further distinguish the two examples, note that you could wrap the first example in anything, not just `data.frame(.)`. Try, for example, `do(df = (.))`, or `do(df = identity(.))`

Comment: @Robinson: Good points. I suspected a difference but didn't pinpoint it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference comes from the `magrittr` way of splitting chains.

```
expr1 <- substitute(data.frame(x = rnorm(100)) %>% do(df = .))
expr2 <- substitute(data.frame(x = rnorm(100)) %>% do(df = (.)))

magrittr:::split_chain(expr1)
magrittr:::split_chain(expr2)
```